# Fusion Tables polyline pattern

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

I want to use fusion tables in google maps.
Can anyone could give me polyline pattern for Fusion Tables?
I don't want to use KML files.
Something like [(1,1),(3,3)]

Comment: `<LineString><coordinates>1,1 3,3</coordinates></LineString>`

Comment: Great - that's correct - You saved me lots of work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Dr.Molle pointed out `<LineString><coordinates>1,1 3,3</coordinates></LineString>` works perfectly when you place it in the location field of your GFT. You can even place multiple LineString segmets and it'll treat that as a single entity:

```
<LineString><coordinates>1,1 3,3</coordinates></LineString>
<LineString><coordinates>2,2 4,4</coordinates></LineString>
```

Broken into two lines for readability here, but GFT treats all whitespace (newlines, tabs, spaces) as a single space, so copy-pasting the above into GFT will work too (except if you try to insert it into an SQL Query, then you'll need to replace the newlines yourself).

Answer (score 0):

I just use code like that below to overlay a polygon onto a Fusion Tables-generated map, if that is what you mean.

```
var triangleCoords = [
new google.maps.LatLng(51.620736,-0.443077),
new google.maps.LatLng(51.632233,-0.437060),
new google.maps.LatLng(51.629092,-0.434385),
new google.maps.LatLng(51.625626,-0.434879),
new google.maps.LatLng(51.619795,-0.435577)
];

bermudaTriangle = new google.maps.Polygon({
paths: triangleCoords,
strokeColor: '#FF0000',
strokeOpacity: 0.8,
strokeWeight: 3,
fillColor: '#FF0000',
fillOpacity: 0.35
});

bermudaTriangle.setMap(map);
```

Comment: No, I want to use fusion tables as source of polylines but those polylines as string not kml

Comment: Just to clarify, those polylines are in fact KML fragments.